# Fixing the tab border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make tab panel with two tabs over the entire width in `HTML`. I found and example, but I have a tiny problem. When I select the second tab, there is a break between right tab border and right panel border.

[image]

What should I do? Help me please fix it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppf083f4/5/)

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/ppf083f4/6/

Comment: There is 1px difference because of the border.
Content div can be 299px

Comment: @Hashem Qolami, there must be no bottom border in the selected tab.

Comment: @olgacosta Then remove `border-bottom` from `ul.tabs`: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ppf083f4/8/

Comment: @Hashem Qolami, there is still a gap.

Comment: @olgacosta Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/wa1dLahx/

Comment: @Mary Melody, this is what I wanted! Write, please, an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by adding the `border-right` to `.tabs` and remove the `border-right` from `li:nth-child(2)` like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ktp97pgo/)**

```
.tabs > li:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: none;
}
.tabs {
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position:relative` to your `.tab_container` and try to move it a bit - `bottom:1px`.

Also Reduce width of this element by 1px - `width:299px`

Working demo:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ppf083f4/7/)

Comment: your version looks interesting, but you deleted bottom border of tabs. I'd like to solve the problem using border styles.